# Improve TimescaleDB aggregate query execution time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, timescaledb

## Schema

The following database schema is realized in a PostgreSQL 14.2 database with TimescaleDB 2.5.1:

[image: Database Schema]

Indexes on tables exist for primary and foreign keys. As an example, this is the output of `\d muscle_actions`, one of the tables that are most prominently queried:

```
                                            Table "public.muscle_actions"
       Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                   
--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('muscle_actions_id_seq'::regclass)
 agent_id           | integer                     |           |          | 
 simtimes           | json                        |           | not null | 
 walltime           | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 sensor_readings    | json                        |           |          | 
 actuator_setpoints | json                        |           |          | 
 rewards            | json                        |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "pk__muscle_actions" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix__muscle_actions_agent_id" btree (agent_id)
    "ix__muscle_actions_id" UNIQUE, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk__muscle_actions__agent_id__agents" FOREIGN KEY (agent_id) REFERENCES agents(id)
Triggers:
    ts_insert_blocker BEFORE INSERT ON muscle_actions FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION _timescaledb_internal.insert_blocker()
Number of child tables: 17499 (Use \d+ to list them.)
```

The Hypertable is partitioned by `id` and `walltime`. I.e., executing the following query yields:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_path_query_array(CAST(muscle_actions.sensor_readings AS JSONB), '$.*.value')) AS vm FROM muscle_actions LIMIT 10000;
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..72.79 rows=10000 width=32) (actual time=0.762..37.343 rows=10000 loops=1)
  ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..54406118.67 rows=7474185600 width=32) (actual time=0.761..36.597 rows=10000 loops=1)
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..15914062.83 rows=74741856 width=936) (actual time=0.707..8.913 rows=2000 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on muscle_actions muscle_actions_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.038..0.039 rows=0 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_1_17528_chunk muscle_actions_2  (cost=0.00..5798.08 rows=27608 width=574) (actual time=0.667..8.010 rows=2000 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_1_17529_chunk muscle_actions_3  (cost=0.00..23638.06 rows=112606 width=573) (never executed)
              ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_2_10000_chunk muscle_actions_4  (cost=0.00..5100.76 rows=24576 width=936) (never executed)
...
```

(I intentionally left out another 17497 skipped seq scans)

(*Update:* Adding a composite index over `agent_id`, `id`, and `walltime` as suggested by [TimescaleDB](https://www.timescale.com/blog/use-composite-indexes-to-speed-up-time-series-queries-sql-8ca2df6b3aaa/) does not change the query plan.)

## Query

The database stores results from experiments, so analyses usually try to aggregate data before we shovel rows into Jupyter Notebooks to conduct more number crunching, statistical analysis, and plotting using pandas, Dask, etc. The following query is a prime example for typical queries that run against the database:

```sql
WITH voltages AS
  (SELECT muscle_actions.id AS id,
          regexp_replace(CAST(((((((((experiment_runs.document_json -> 'schedule_config') -> 0) -> 'phase_0') -> 'environments') -> 0) -> 'environment') -> 'params') -> 'reward') -> 'name' AS TEXT), '^[^:]+:([^"]+)"', '\\1') AS reward_function,
          agents.uid AS agent,
          jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_path_query_array(CAST(muscle_actions.sensor_readings AS JSONB), '$.*.value')) AS vm
   FROM muscle_actions
   JOIN agents ON agents.id = muscle_actions.agent_id
   JOIN experiment_run_phases ON experiment_run_phases.id = agents.experiment_run_phase_id
   JOIN experiment_run_instances ON experiment_run_instances.id = experiment_run_phases.experiment_run_instance_id
   JOIN experiment_runs ON experiment_runs.id = experiment_run_instances.experiment_run_id
   WHERE experiment_runs.id IN (8, 11, 19,
-- ... about 200 IDs more ...
                                228)
     AND experiment_run_phases.uid = 'phase_1'),
     vm_per_bus AS
  (SELECT voltages.id AS id,
          voltages.reward_function AS reward_function,
          voltages.agent AS agent,
          voltages.vm AS vm,
          abs(1.0 - CAST(voltages.vm AS REAL)) AS vm_deviation,
          abs(1.0 - CAST(voltages.vm AS REAL)) >= 0.15 AS vm_violation
   FROM voltages),
     vm AS
  (SELECT vm_per_bus.id AS id,
          max(vm_per_bus.reward_function) AS reward_function,
          max(vm_per_bus.agent) AS agent,
          array_agg(vm_per_bus.vm) AS array_agg_1,
          max(vm_per_bus.vm_deviation) AS max_vm_deviation,
          sum(CAST(vm_per_bus.vm_violation AS INTEGER)) AS num_vm_violations
   FROM vm_per_bus
   GROUP BY vm_per_bus.id)
SELECT vm.reward_function,
       vm.agent,
       max(vm.max_vm_deviation) AS max_abs_violation,
       sum(vm.num_vm_violations) AS num_violations
FROM vm
GROUP BY vm.reward_function,
         vm.agent
```

## The Problem

This query in particular runs for two days now. Obviously, I'd like to find out *why*, and how I can speed things up. I have a number of knobs where I can tweak things, such as:

- Requesting more RAM or CPU cores from our IT service desk
- Changing any setting in the `postgresql.conf` file
- Changing the structure of the DB (e.g., adding indexes, etc.)

Of course I know that, for example, "more RAM helps more", but instead of blindly throwing more resources at it, I'd like to know what would bring the most benefit, and why. In summary, **I would like to find out what the bottleneck in this query's execution is, and how I can solve it.** For this, I will try to provide as much information as possible; missing data (requests from comments) can be added promptly.

## Query Plan

Executing `EXPLAIN` on the query gives me the following query plan. **Please note** that in the following plan, I cut most of the `Seq Scan` entries. In fact, there are 17.500 sequential scans in the query plan, but I've left only 4 in the uploaded JSON file. Also, the query now contains only 1 value for `experiment_runs.id` instead of 200. This has been done to stay within the limits of what, e.g., Dalibo Explain can show. A graphical analysis is available on [Dalibo Explain](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/OXx).

From it, to me it seems obvious that the problem is the huge amount of sequential scans, which, I assume, are I/O bound. But since the query on the `muscle_actions` relation is dominated by the `JOIN` on the foreign key `agent_id`, for which there is an index, I would also have assumed that the btree index will be the faster access method to the data?

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=21762068.49..21762073.49 rows=200 width=104)
"  Group Key: vm.reward_function, vm.agent"
  ->  Sort  (cost=21762068.49..21762068.99 rows=200 width=80)
"        Sort Key: vm.reward_function, vm.agent"
        ->  Subquery Scan on vm  (cost=21762005.18..21762060.85 rows=200 width=80)
              ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=21762005.18..21762058.85 rows=200 width=116)
                    Group Key: muscle_actions.id
                    ->  Gather Merge  (cost=21762005.18..21762051.85 rows=400 width=84)
                          Workers Planned: 2
                          ->  Sort  (cost=21761005.16..21761005.66 rows=200 width=84)
                                Sort Key: muscle_actions.id
                                ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=21760995.51..21760997.51 rows=200 width=84)
                                      Group Key: muscle_actions.id
                                      ->  ProjectSet  (cost=454.09..20789573.27 rows=952374800 width=120)
                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=454.09..15599130.61 rows=9523748 width=1016)
                                                  Hash Cond: (muscle_actions.agent_id = agents.id)
                                                  ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..15386812.75 rows=31131002 width=944)
                                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_1_17529_chunk muscle_actions_3  (cost=0.00..22981.19 rows=46919 width=581)
--                                                          ... 482 more of those, with identical costs & width
```

## PostgreSQL Configuration

This is the content of `postgresql.conf`, with all standard values or comments removed:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
shared_buffers = 1989MB                 # min 128kB
work_mem = 2MB                          # min 64kB
maintenance_work_mem = 1018584kB                # min 1MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix      # the default is the first option
bgwriter_delay = 2000ms                 # 10-10000ms between rounds
effective_io_concurrency = 256          # 1-1000; 0 disables prefetching
max_worker_processes = 13               # (change requires restart)
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2     # taken from max_parallel_workers
max_parallel_workers = 3                # maximum number of max_worker_processes that
wal_writer_delay = 5000ms               # 1-10000 milliseconds
checkpoint_timeout = 15min              # range 30s-1d
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9      # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
max_wal_size = 1GB
min_wal_size = 512MB
random_page_cost = 1.1                  # same scale as above
effective_cache_size = 4096MB
default_statistics_target = 500 # range 1-10000
log_timezone = 'UTC'
autovacuum_max_workers = 10             # max number of autovacuum subprocesses
autovacuum_naptime = 10         # time between autovacuum runs
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'UTC'
lc_messages = 'en_US.utf8'                      # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'en_US.utf8'                      # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_US.utf8'                       # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_US.utf8'                          # locale for time formatting
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'        # (change requires restart)
max_locks_per_transaction = 4096        # min 10
timescaledb.telemetry_level=off
timescaledb.max_background_workers = 8
timescaledb.last_tuned = '2022-03-29T21:20:33Z'
timescaledb.last_tuned_version = '0.12.0'
```

Comment: Ideally we need to see where the time is currently going. I suggest we start by reducing the amount of `experiment_runs.id` values being filtered (assuming that will allow it to complete in a reasonable amount of time) and get a plan with real statistics from there. Use something like https://explain.dalibo.com/ to share these details so that they can be analysed easily. Double check it's doing a similar plan for your 200 IDs. The part of your plan that you have shared doesn't really give us anything - can you upload the full estimate to https://explain.dalibo.com/

Comment: I think this question isn't worth a second glance without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: i fear the query plan is too large for dalibo, at least that is what the site returns (its 46372068 lines). And that is with just one ID (and not 200). Are there any other options, or am I doing something wrong? The JSON was extracted with `psql -XqAt`

Comment: Have you tried to build a [continuous aggregates](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/continuous-aggregates/about-continuous-aggregates/) to pre-process some parts of your query in background?

Comment: I haven't. The reason is that while the query's structure is pretty common, the data is not. Attributes like `sensor_readings` of the `muscle_actions` relation are JSON because the data being stored here depends on the experiment. I would have loved to "explode" all relevant data into sub-tables, but I cannot even be sure that every sensor reading is a scalar. It might also be a vector or a matrix (e.g., image sensors). So for now the only approach I can think of is storing JSON documents.

Comment: Update: I've managed to cut most of the seq scan entries from the JSON, so that I could upload it to dalibo explain. I've updated the question accordingly. From the 17.500 seq scans in the query plan, there are now only 4 left in the analysis. But all bear the same costs.

Comment: Update: I have added a composite index as the TimescaleDB developers suggest, but that does not change the number of sequential scans (17.500).

Comment: What are the timescaledb partitioning settings on table muscle_actions? Is it partitioned on agent_id to quickly eliminate partitions that won't be hit by the query?

Comment: Also can you run this to get a feel of how slow the data access is: EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_path_query_array(CAST(muscle_actions.sensor_readings AS JSONB), '$.*.value')) AS vm
   FROM muscle_actions
   LIMIT 10000;

Comment: Note that you are using json data type, which means the query is re-parsing millions of json documents on each run to extract one scalar from each. I feel the timing of the above EXPLAIN is going to be, uh... enlightening...

Comment: Thanks! The Hypertable is only partitioned by `id` and `walltime`. I've updated the initial question accordingly. The partitioning seems to be an obvious mistake (in hindsight). How can I repartition the hypertable to test that theory?